# IF statement doesn't work on jquery

Tags: javascript

Hello I need help this my code and it always goes to else condition 
I want to comapre a text from dropdown if the value and text matches then I want to hide some div's :

```
jQuery("#myid").on('change', function () {
    if(jQuery('#myid').val() == 'Well, this is a dummy text') {
        alert(" hello");
    } else {
        alert("World");
    }
});



<select name="testtype" id="myid" class="validate[required]" style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial">
                <option selected="selected" value="">-- Make your selection --</option>
                <option id="first" value="Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives ">Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives </option>
                <option value="Supervisory-English only">Supervisory-English only</option>
                <option value="Health, Safety and Environment Test for Managers and Professionals -English only">Health, Safety and Environment Test for Managers and Professionals -English only</option>
                <option value="Demolition-English only">Demolition-English only</option>
                <option value="Highway Works-English only">Highway Works-English only</option>
                <option value="Specialist Work at Hight-English only">Specialist Work at Hight-English only</option>
                <option value="Lifts and Escalators-English only">Lifts and Escalators-English only</option>
                <option value="Tunnelling-English only">Tunnelling-English only</option>
                <option value="Heating, Ventilation Air Conditioning and Refrigeration (HAVCR)-English only">Heating, Ventilation Air Conditioning and Refrigeration (HAVCR)-English only</option>
                <option value="Plumbing (JIB)-English only">Plumbing (JIB)-English only</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: How do you expect anybody to help with that? Only you can know what `jQuery('#myid').val()` is and thus why the condition fails.

Comment: Show us Html code too !

Comment: what element belong to #myid

Comment: select id is #myid

Comment: share html for element `#myid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to comapre a text from dropdown

It looks like you want to match the text of the selected option not the value, then you should get the text using `.text()` instead of `.val()` that will return the value, the selector should be like :

```
jQuery('#myid option:selected').text()
```

Code:

```js
jQuery("#myid").on('change', function() {
  //if (jQuery('#myid option:selected').text() == ...){
  //Or
  if (jQuery(this).val() == 'Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives ') {
    alert(" hello");
  } else {
    alert("World");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="testtype" id="myid" class="validate[required]" style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial">
  <option selected="selected" value="">-- Make your selection --</option>
  <option id="first" value="Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives ">Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives </option>
  <option value="Supervisory-English only">Supervisory-English only</option>
  <option value="Health, Safety and Environment Test for Managers and Professionals -English only">Health, Safety and Environment Test for Managers and Professionals -English only</option>
  <option value="Demolition-English only">Demolition-English only</option>
  <option value="Highway Works-English only">Highway Works-English only</option>
  <option value="Specialist Work at Hight-English only">Specialist Work at Hight-English only</option>
  <option value="Lifts and Escalators-English only">Lifts and Escalators-English only</option>
  <option value="Tunnelling-English only">Tunnelling-English only</option>
  <option value="Heating, Ventilation Air Conditioning and Refrigeration (HAVCR)-English only">Heating, Ventilation Air Conditioning and Refrigeration (HAVCR)-English only</option>
  <option value="Plumbing (JIB)-English only">Plumbing (JIB)-English only</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, this is a dummy text this is text and value too it doesn't alert the hello

Comment: Ok please show us your version of the dropdown HTML code.

Comment: see question and I want to display hello on <option id="first" value="Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives ">Health, Safety and Environment Test for Operatives </option>

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is you have assigned value of options to number & you are comparing with it so it returns false on `if` statement. but

> if you compare with `.text()` it gets all text from every option
>   that's why it fails in if statement

```js
$("#myid").change(function(){

  if( $(this).val()=='Well,this is a dummy text' ) {
    alert('hello');
  }
  else
    alert("wolrd");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="myid">
<option value="1">wolrd</option>
<option value="2">hello</option>
<option value="Well,this is a dummy text">Well,this is a dummy text</option>

</select>
```